# Create a constructor property that can be more than one type?

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

Hi I am curious to know how to create a constructor property in C# that can be more than one type.

I have looked at stack overflow links:

[How to parse JSON string that can be one of two different strongly typed objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254809/how-to-parse-json-string-that-can-be-one-of-two-different-strongly-typed-objects)

[A variable of two types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395609/a-variable-of-two-types)

...but they don't seem to match my inquiry.

I can produce what I want in python as per below. 
IE initialise an object of class "this_thing" that can take an object of class "thing" or "thingy".

A working Python equivalent of what I want to do is:

```
class thing:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._number
    @number.setter
    def number(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError('"number" must be an int')
        self._number = value

class thingy:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text= text
    @property
    def text(self):
        return self._text
    @text.setter
    def text(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError('"text" must be a str')
        self._text = value

class this_thing:
    def __init__(self, chosen_thing, name_of_the_thing):
        self.chosen_thing = chosen_thing
        self.name_of_the_thing = name_of_the_thing 
    @property
    def chosen_thing(self):
        return self._chosen_thing
    @chosen_thing.setter
    def chosen_thing(self, value):
        if (not isinstance(value, (thing, thingy))):
            raise TypeError('"chosen_thing" must be a thing or thingy')
        self._chosen_thing = value

    @property
    def name_of_the_thing(self):
        return self._name_of_the_thing
    @name_of_the_thing.setter
    def name_of_the_thing(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError('"name_of_the_thing" must be a str')
        self._name_of_the_thing = value

some_thing = thing(10)
another_thing = thingy("10")
new_thing = this_thing(some_thing, "Some Thing")
another_new_thing = this_thing(another_thing, "Another Thing")
```

In C#, I have classes "Thing" and "Thingy" that work on their own.
But I want to create a new class "ThisThing" which can take either an object of class "Thing" or "Thingy", but I'm not sure how to enable this action. IE declare / enable an object property to be of multiple types.

```
namespace TheManyThings
{
    class ThisThing
    {
        public Thing | Thingy NewThing { get; set; }
        public string NameOfTheThing { get; set; }

        public ThisThing(Thing | Thingy newThing, string nameOfTheThing)
        {
            NewThing = newThing;
            NameOfTheThing = nameOfTheThing
        }
    }
}
```

After playing around in C# it looks like the most workable solution was to just separate class "ThisThing" into two separate classes. It seems perhaps C# is not as flexible as Python with manipulating class types. Please of course comment, if you do know how to reproduce the above python code in C#. That would be handy to know.

```
namespace TheManyThings
{
    class ThisThing0
    {
        public Thing NewThing { get; set; }
        public string NameOfTheThing { get; set; }

        public ThisThing0(Thing newThing, string nameOfTheThing)
        {
            NewThing = newThing;
            NameOfTheThing = nameOfTheThing
        }
    }

    class ThisThing1
    {
        public Thingy NewThingy { get; set; }
        public string NameOfTheThing { get; set; }

        public ThisThing1(Thingy newThingy, string nameOfTheThing)
        {
            NewThingy = newThingy;
            NameOfTheThing = nameOfTheThing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare `Thing` and `Thingy` to inherit some base class. And your property's type should be this class.

Comment: You should read about the basic principles of OOP in C#. This is a problem that is solvable by using a base-`class` or an `interface` from which both "Things" inherit.

Comment: @smokescreen899 If the two types don't have a common base class, your best bet is to add **two separate constructors** with different parameters. One for `Thing`, one for `Thingy`.

Comment: You could also use generics (`ThisThing<T>`) depending on what your higher-level requirements are.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for your suggestion. 
Is there any way to implement your suggestion of having two separate constructors as you say, without the need to duplicate all of the class methods (as a result of the new parameters)?

Comment: I can't use inheritance unless someone can suggest a way that I can create an object type that will take a daughter class, but not the parent class for one of its' parameters. I am open to suggestions if there are ways to do so.

Comment: It's not so straight forward. To add some more context there also exists another class "TheMainThing" which takes parameters of types ("Thing", Thingy", "Thingy") in that order. If "Thingy" inherits from "Thing" how can you prevent someone accidentally initialising on object of type "TheMainThing" with the wrong combination of object types? IE One of the "Thingy"s is accidentally loaded with a "Thing" instead?

Comment: `without the need to duplicate all of the class methods` Have a third private constructor which does the common work. The two constructors can then call the common constructor.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for your reply. I'll have a go at implementing what you have suggested. If I resolve the issue, I'll post here saying it was resolved. If I'm still stuck, I'll modify the initial code I posted above to reflect this new implementation, to see if it is close to what you meant.

Comment: @mjwills I was not successful in implementing your suggestion. I have updated the above blurb to reflect what I have tried. Is there a C# equivalent to replicate the code in the above python class "this_thing" that is able to initialise its' "chosen_thing" with an object of type "thing" or "thingy". C# is a tad more restrictive, and I'm not sure how to go about this without making two separate classes for "ThisThing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you can replicate a dynamically typed system in C# by using `dynamic`, or a weak type like `object`.

But then, as you've done in Python, you will need to continually do type conformance checking at run time

As a result, you'll lose most of the benefits of a statically typed language like C#, and you'll also draw a lot of scorn from the [SOLID OO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) community.

**Here's a conversion of your original Python code using `dynamic` (DON'T do this)**

```
public class Thing
{
    public Thing(int number) { Number = number; }
    public int Number { get; }
}

public class Thingy
{
    public Thingy(string text) { Text = text; }
    public string Text { get; }
}

public class ThisThing
{
    public ThisThing(dynamic chosenThing, string nameOfTheThing)
    {
        ChosenThing = chosenThing;
        NameOfTheThing = nameOfTheThing;
    }

    // Cache the accepted types
    private static readonly ICollection<Type> AcceptedTypes = new HashSet<Type> { typeof(Thing), typeof(Thingy) };
    private dynamic _chosenThing;
    public dynamic ChosenThing
    {
        get => _chosenThing;
        private set
        {
            if (!AcceptedTypes.Contains(value.GetType()))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"ChosenThing must be {string.Join(" or ", AcceptedTypes.Select(t => t.Name))}");
            }
            _chosenThing = value;
        }
    }

    public string NameOfTheThing { get; }
}
```

And as per your test cases, the following can be done:

```
var someThing = new Thing(10);
var anotherThing = new Thingy("10");
var newThing = new ThisThing(someThing, "Some Thing");
var anotherNewThing = new ThisThing(anotherThing, "Some Thing");

Console.WriteLine(newThing.ChosenThing.Number);
Console.WriteLine(anotherNewThing.ChosenThing.Text);
```

The problem with weak typing is that errors are only picked up at run time. 
The below will all get past the compiler (because `ChosenThing` is `dynamic`) but will crash at run time.

```
var invalidThing = new ThisThing("Invalid for string types", "Invalid");
// newThing has a Number, not a Text property
Console.WriteLine(newThing.ChosenThing.Text);
// Vice Versa
Console.WriteLine(anotherNewThing.ChosenThing.Number);
```

**Better approach using common interfaces**

A far more acceptable OO approach is to have a common base class or interface to your 'acceptable' types, and then to use this instead. This way you will get compile-time type safety checking.

```
// Common interface
public interface IThing { }

public class Thing : IThing
{
    public Thing(int number) { Number = number; }
    public int Number { get; }
}

public class Thingy : IThing
{
    public Thingy(string text) { Text = text; }
    public string Text { get; }
}
```

Because of the common interface, `IThing` can now be used to constrain the permissable types passed to `ThisThing` (i.e. must conform to the `IThing` contract), and these type constraints are enforced at compile time:

```
public class ThisThing
{
    public ThisThing(IThing chosenThing, string nameOfTheThing)
    {
        ChosenThing = chosenThing;
        NameOfTheThing = nameOfTheThing;
    }

    public IThing ChosenThing { get; }

    public string NameOfTheThing { get; }
}
```

You would now expose any common functionality between `Thing` and `Thingy` via the `IThing` contract.

As it stands, the interface has no commonality, so you would need to downcast the `IThing` to one of the subclasses, which again, violates the [SOLID Liskov Substitution Principal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20861107):

```
Console.WriteLine(((Thing)newThing.ChosenThing).Number);
Console.WriteLine(((Thingy)anotherNewThing.ChosenThing).Text);
```

So what you really want is to abstract commonality, e.g.

```
public interface IThing 
{ 
     int CalculateValue();
}
```

Both `Thing` and `Thingy` would now be forced to provide an implementation for this abstraction, and then consumers of the interface would now be able to use the interface safely without any further assumptions about the actual type of the concrete instance:

```
Console.WriteLine(anyIThing.CalculateValue());
```

Comment: Thank you for the phenomenal response, and the effort you went to explaining the differences between the "equivalent" and "best practice". I have successfully implemented my C# equivalent code based on the common interface approach. Many thanks!

Comment: Only thing I do want to share (and it may potentially depend on other factors) I had to remove the "public" in front of the abstract methods contained within the public interface declaration. But apart from that, it worked a treat. Thanks again for your solid effort.

Comment: Oops - my bad, yes, interface methods / properties / events can't have scope qualifiers. I've removed the public.